# Proper JavaScript to show/hide inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to know the proper function loop code for show/hide method.
This is the javascript for show/hide for the first (1) radio button:

```
function showHide(){
    var chckbox = document.getElementById("chk");
    var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

    for(var i=0; i !=hiddeninputs.length; i++){
        if(chckbox.checked){
            hiddeninputs[i].style.display ="block";
        }
        else{
            hiddeninputs[i].style.display ="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Yet I need the proper loop for having multiple objects (checkboxes) with seperated show/hide method. This is the first checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this.checked);"/>
    <label for="chk">Billing & Credit Management Systems</label>

<div class="hidden">
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Web Billin  g </label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRIBS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> PPC </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area1" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>
```

And I need the loop code in order to prompt the show/hide to the following objects:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk1" onclick="showHide(this.checked);"/>
    <label for="chk1">Customer Care Systems</label>

<div class="hidden">
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRM (Customer Relationship) </label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> MVNO CRM </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Self-Care Site </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CMS (Trouble Ticketing) </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> IRS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Online Guide </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> TMOS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area2" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>
```

Only the first checkbox prompts while the second one doesn't whenever I checked.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but be sure to accept an answer that works for you. The credit can help go toward future bounties, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not the exact answer you're looking for, but a bit simpler (less looping). Let me know if this works for you, I'll try my best to explain what's happening here.

I implemented this solution with the intention of forcing you to change as little as possible.

1) Assign a unique attribute to the checkbox and the div it belongs to. In this case I used "data-menu". In the onclick function, pass "this" instance of the element into the function showHide.

```
<input data-menu="1" type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this);"/>

<div class="hidden" data-menu="1">
```

2) Use the css class 'hidden' to hide your menu options.

```
.hidden {

  display: none;

}
```

3) Re-work your JS function to dynamically add the hidden class when the box is checked. Since your menus are off by default, checking on naturally turns them on.

```
function showHide(e){

    var menu = document.querySelector('div[data-menu="'+e.getAttribute('data-menu')+'"');
    menu.classList.toggle('hidden');

}
```

Check out the below *working* snippet to see it in action.

```js
function showHide(e){
    
    var menu = document.querySelector('div[data-menu="'+e.getAttribute('data-menu')+'"');
    menu.classList.toggle('hidden');

}
```

```css
.hidden {

  display: none;

}
```

```html
<input data-menu="1" type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this);"/>
    <label for="chk">Billing &amp; Credit Management Systems</label>

<div class="hidden" data-menu="1">
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Web Billin  g </label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRIBS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> PPC </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area1" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>

<input data-menu="2" type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk1" onclick="showHide(this);"/>
    <label for="chk1">Customer Care Systems</label>

<div data-menu="2" class="hidden">
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRM (Customer Relationship) </label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> MVNO CRM </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Self-Care Site </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CMS (Trouble Ticketing) </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> IRS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Online Guide </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> TMOS </label>  <br />
<input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area2" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function showHide(element){
      var chckbox = document.getElementById(element);
      var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName(element);

      for(var i=0; i !=hiddeninputs.length; i++){
          if(chckbox.checked){
              hiddeninputs[i].style.display ="block";
          }
          else{
              hiddeninputs[i].style.display ="none";
          }
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this.id);"/>
     <label for="chk">Billing & Credit Management Systems</label>
 
 <div class="chk">
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Web Billin  g </label> <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRIBS </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> PPC </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area1" placeholder="Please  Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
 </div> <br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk1" onclick="showHide(this.id);"/>
    <label for="chk1">Customer Care Systems</label>

 <div class="chk1">
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRM (Customer Relationship) </label> <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> MVNO CRM </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Self-Care Site </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CMS (Trouble Ticketing) </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> IRS </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Online Guide </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> TMOS </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area2" placeholder="Please  Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
 </div>
</body>
</html>

try this this will work fine for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the parameter you're providing in the call of your function.

```
var chckbox = document.getElementById("chk");
```

will always find the first checkbox only to know if the other fields should be hidden or not and

```
var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
```

will allways hide all elements with class hidden. I think that

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onclick="showHide(this);"/>
```

(i.e. change the parameter to the element rather than the .checked) in combination with

```
function showHide(elem){
    var selector = "#" + elem.id + " ~ .hidden";
    document.querySelector(selector).style.display = elem.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

will do more of what you want

Answer (score 0):

call **onchange** function in input type checkbox

example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk" onchange="valueChanged(this.id)"/>Billing & Credit Management Systems
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="chk1" onchange="valueChanged(this.id)"/> Customer Care Systems

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready( function(){

     $(".hidden").hide();
     $(".hidden2").hide();

 });

 function valueChanged(id){

     if(id== "chk"){
         if($('#chk').is(":checked"))   
            $(".hidden").show();
         else
            $(".hidden").hide();
     }

     if(id== "chk1"){
        if($('#chk1').is(":checked"))   
            $(".hidden2").show();
        else
            $(".hidden2").hide();
     }

  }
</script>

<div class="hidden">
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Web Billin  g </label> <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRIBS </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> PPC </label>  <br />
 <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area1" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>

<div class="hidden2">
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CRM (Customer Relationship) </label> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> MVNO CRM </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Self-Care Site </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> CMS (Trouble Ticketing) </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> IRS </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Online Guide </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> TMOS </label>  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="area1" /> <label> Others <input type="text" name="area2" placeholder="Please Specify"/></label><br /></label>  <br />
</div>
```